# Make div 'fullscreen' onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that I want to go full-screen (100% width/height of Window size) onClick of a button.
How would I go about this using Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/QxMux/1/)

```
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).css({
      position:'absolute', //or fixed depending on needs
      top: $(window).scrollTop(), // top pos based on scoll pos
      left: 0,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I make the div full-screen onClick of a seperate button? And how can I make it return to the previous size? My JS skills are limited!

Comment: @michaelhanon Feel free to post an answer you think is better.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.yourdivclass').click(function(){
    $(this).css('height','100%').css('width','100%');
})
```

Comment: You can also try `$(this).height('100%').width('100%');`

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? What didn't work?
Take a look at that:

http://jsfiddle.net/6BP9t/1/

```
$('#box').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).css({
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
$('#idOfDiv').click(function() {
  $(this).css({position:'fixed', height: '100%', width: '100%'});
});​
```

jsfiffle: http://jsfiddle.net/P6tgH/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var win = $(window),
        h = win.height(),
        w = win.width();
    $(this).css({ height: h, width: w });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TQA4z/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate to the answer marked as correct. Plus it gives him what he asked for to close the div.

Using toggle class is much easier than having your css in your jquery. Do everything you can do to keep css separate from JavaScript.

For some reason my https is effecting loading of the JavaScript on load of that jsfiddle page. I clicked on the Shield icon in chrome address bar and chose to run scripts.

[Toggle Class Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/QxMux/212/)

Something like

```
$('#buttonID').click(function() {
 $("div > div").toggleClass("Class you want to add");
});
```